# how to add new type to an existing class or object in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to add a new type to an existing class(object?) that fetch from database table (with entity framework class) in Microsoft MVC.
i.e:
my person class {f_name, l_name}
how can i add new type to this objects when i loop throw it?
like:

```
// Person class stracture is:
public Person()
{
    public string f_name { get; set; }
    public string l_name { get; set; }
}
```

i want to add 'age' to it without add this to model

```
var all_persons = db.Person.toList();
for (var item in all_person)
{
    item.age = some_value;
}
return View(all_persons);
```

Comment: what type you want to add ?

Comment: Your need to create another model (which can derive from `Person` that contains a property `int age`) and then project your query to it.

Comment: i don't want new property (age in here) save in my model (and database table) and just want to show additional dynamic value with it

Comment: Show us what you would like to do as an example... Type the code you would think it would be although it doesn't work so we can see the dynamic value because it's a little tricky.  I want to suggest using a Select(p => new...) but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `public class PersonVM : Person { public int Age { get; set; } }` and `var all_persons = db.Person.Select(x => new PersonVM{ f_name = x.f_name, l_name = x.l_name, age = number });`, and your view is `@model IEnumerable<PersonVM>`  - but where does the value of `number` come fro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example using Entity Framework :**

If you are using code-first approach then [NotMapped] will work fine for you.

But if you are using model-first approach then it will not work because if you are going to update your model its going to be updated according to .tt template of model and create a class with only properties in tables.

So, what now ? here comes the concept of partial class.

model generated from EF :

```
namespace EF.Model
{
   public partial class Person
   {
       public string f_name { get; set; }
       public string l_name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

So to add additional properties that you don't want EF to map while CRUD operations. Add a new partial class in the same project with same class name and same namespace as of EF model

```
namespace EF.Model
{
       public partial class Person
       {
           public string fullName { get; set; }
           public int age { get; set; }
       }
}
```

So now you can do like this.

```
var all_persons = db.Person.toList();
for (var item in all_person)
{
    item.age = some_value;
    item.fullName = item.f_name + item.l_name;
}
return View(all_persons);
```

I hope this would give you a better understanding. You should read about partial classes.
https://www.dotnetperls.com/partial

Answer (score 2):

Add a `[NotMapped]` (assuming you dont want this property to be mapped to database) in your `Person` class:

```
[NotMapped]
public int Age {get; set;}
```

Or create a view model instead of using EF model directly

Answer (score 1):

You can add the new property in a linq Select as follows:

```
    void AddNewField(int number)
    {
        var all_persons = new db.Person.Select(x => new { x.f_name, x.l_name, age = number });
        return View(all_persons);
    }
```

This will save you having to actually add the new field to the model.

Comment: i just want to return new data and not to save it or change base Person class.

Comment: It's not going to save in your database when you update the age unless you specify for it to do so.